# How to make this delete test independent?

Tags: java, api, testng, rest-assured

I want to check DELETE response. So should I make employee in this test or it should be in a different place(Before method for example)?

```
      @Test(description="positive")
public static void deleteEmployeeEducation()       
    Response res= given().
                      spec(Specifications.getRequestSpecAsEmpl()).              
        body(Payloads.addEmployeeEducation("GGGG","ingieneer",2005,2010)).
                      when().
                      put(Endpoints.createEmployeeEducation()).
                      then().log().all().extract().response();
    JsonPath js= ReusableMethods.rawToJson(res);
    Integer  educationId=js.get("[0].id");

        given().
                spec(Specifications.getRequestSpecAsEmpl()).
                delete(Endpoints.deleteEmployeeEducation()+educationId).
                then().log().all().
                assertThat().statusCode(204);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your delete test to be independent, then yes, it makes sense to first create the user in this test, then assert that deleting it works. The logical prerequisite is that an insert test has been successfully tested beforehand.

I wouldn't necessarily advise that you seek to make this delete test independent, however. Typically, in cases like this where you're testing CRUD operations provided by an API, it makes sense to have an integration test, with a logical order. If your API exposes insert, select, delete, update operations, then an integration test could be this sequence of tests, in this order:

- Test insert works, with user 123
- Test select works and returns user 123
- Test update works, and updates user 123 to user 234. Probably add a select assertion within this test, and assert the select returns user 234
- Test delete works. Probably add a select assertion which asserts no user is returned.

That would be my advice for the design of your test class, if I am correct in understanding that you're simply testing different CRUD operations.

The @Before method should be used for setting up prerequisites for the tests. It can make sense to create your employee in here if all your tests relate to the same employee. Otherwise, I would recommend my approach with the integration test.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Is it better to make one CRUD test? (@Test CRUDEmployee()) or four dependent tests? (@Test createEmpl(){abc}; @Test readEmpl(abc),...)?

Comment: 4 tests. You're testing each operation, you're not testing the actual employee. And if one fails, it will be clear and concise which operation is faulty.